# Java Multicast Sender + Receiver

Tags: java, sockets, multicast

my problem is simple to explain. I have a multicast sender and a multicast receiver. I tried  to send a 8MB big file. It should be split up in 1024 Byte packages + 4 byte header. The send is ok but the reciever cancels receiving at position 5000 sometimes at 2000 or 3000. I don't know why it's not receiving all elements.

THE SENDER:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;

public class Sender extends Thread{

protected static MulticastSocket socket = null;
public int QuoteCount = 0;
public int Time_Interval = 6000;
public static FileInputStream in;
final static int split_size = 1028 ;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // args 0 => path
    // args1=> ip multicast
    // args2 => networkinterface ip
    // args3 => port 
    // args4 => ttl
    //socket = new MulticastSocket(444);
    InetAddress ip_address_group = InetAddress.getByName(args[1]);
    System.out.println("Wait 4 clients to connect...");
    File file=new File(args[0]);

    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(args[1],Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress(args[2], Integer.parseInt(args[3])));
    socket.connect(address);
    socket.setTimeToLive(Integer.parseInt(args[4]));

    MD5 md5 = new MD5();
    try {
        System.out.println("MD5 vom File: "+md5.getFileMD5(args[0]));
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Filesize package
    int filesize = (int)file.length();

    double anzpak=(filesize/1028); // anzahl pakete
    double diagrammgrenze=(80/anzpak); // wieviele stricherl setzt ein paket
    double strikecount=0;
    System.out.println("DIAGR: "+diagrammgrenze +" Anzpak: "+anzpak);

    byte[] firstpack=new byte[4];
    int2bytearr(filesize,firstpack);
    DatagramPacket firsttosend=new DatagramPacket(firstpack,firstpack.length,ip_address_group, Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
    socket.send(firsttosend);

    // Rest of packages
    in = new FileInputStream(file);

    byte[] data = new byte[split_size];
    int numbytes = 0;
    int seqnr = 0;
    int sentbytes=0;

    try {
        while((numbytes = in.read(data)) != -1){
            // Generate 4 byte long seqnr:
            seqnr++;
            strikecount+=diagrammgrenze;
            if(strikecount>=1){
                for(int i=0;i<(int)strikecount;i++){
                    System.out.print("|");
                    strikecount--;
                }
            }

            byte[] dataseq = new byte[4];
            int2bytearr(seqnr,dataseq);
            sentbytes+=numbytes;

            // DATA PLUS SEQNR Generation 
            byte[] seqplusdata = new byte[dataseq.length + data.length];
            System.arraycopy(dataseq, 0, seqplusdata, 0, dataseq.length);
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, seqplusdata, dataseq.length, data.length);

            // Data Plus Seqnr Sending
            DatagramPacket tosend=new DatagramPacket(seqplusdata,seqplusdata.length);
            socket.send(tosend);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("\nTosend filesize: "+filesize);
    System.out.println("Sent bytes: "+sentbytes);
    //in.close();
    socket.close();
}

public static void int2bytearr(int number,byte[] data){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int shift = i << 3; // i * 8
        data[3-i] = (byte)((number & (0xff << shift)) >>> shift);
    }
}

}
```

THE RECEIVER:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Empfaenger extends Thread{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Empfaenger empfaenger = new Empfaenger();
    empfaenger.start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void run(){
    try{

        //Create socket
        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(12345);

        //Connect to server (must be multicast)
        InetAddress IP_Adress = InetAddress.getByName("228.5.6.7");
        socket.joinGroup(IP_Adress);

        DatagramPacket packet;
        int pcount=0;

        // firstpack for getting filesize package
        byte[] firstpack = new byte[4];
        DatagramPacket firstpacket=new DatagramPacket(firstpack,firstpack.length);
        socket.receive(firstpacket);
        int filesize=makeintfrombyte(firstpack);
        System.out.println("Empfaenger filesize: " + filesize);

        double anzpak=(filesize/1028); // anzahl pakete
        double diagrammgrenze=(80/anzpak); // wieviele stricherl setzt ein paket
        double strikecount=0;

        for(int i=0;i<anzpak;i++){
            System.out.println(pcount + "< "+anzpak);

            strikecount+=diagrammgrenze;
            if(strikecount>=1){
                while(strikecount>=1){
                    System.out.print("|");
                    strikecount--;
                }
            }

            byte[] buf = new byte[1028];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            pcount++;
            //System.out.println("SeqNr. in Bytes: "+buf[0]+"|"+buf[1]+"|" +buf[2]+"|" +buf[3]+"|" + pcount);
        }
        //socket.leaveGroup(IP_Adress);
        //socket.close();

    }catch ( IOException X) {System.out.println(X);}
}

public int makeintfrombyte(byte[] b){
    return b[0] << 24 | (b[1] & 0xff) << 16 | (b[2] & 0xff) << 8 | (b[3] & 0xff);
}

}
```

Here a sample Ouput from to Receivers and one Sender]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UblCa.jpg

EDIT: If we let the sender sleep for (long) 1.0 it works, but it's not the meaning to let the sender sleep :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datagrams do not have guaranteed delivery so it's not an ideal protocol for transfering files. You may want to consider a reliable multicast protocol instead.

Finally, if your send rate is higher than your receive rate you will eventually drop packets. In fact, even if the rates are very similar, any temporary slow down on the receiving side (e.g. scheduler, garbage collector, ...) can be enough to start dropping. Increasing the underlying network buffer size with a call to [setReceiveBufferSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setReceiveBufferSize%28int%29) will give you some margin and greatly improve the behavior. The default is usually at 128K, at least on UX systems; try setting it to a couple of MB.

Comment: the receivebuffersize is in bytes? if i set it to 450kB it works for files under 100MB. But if they get bigger it hast corrupt packages again :/

Comment: @StefanSprenger I wouldn't hesitate to set it even a bit higher, e.g. 4MB.  Then you could optimize the performance of your receiving app. At very high rates, even System.out.println on every packet could start impacting performance. Also, why don't you just allocate buf a single time before the loop?